# pydev - can someone please explain these errors

Tags: python, pydev

I am developing using PyDev in Eclipse. I have put in some comments in my code. I get wavy red lines underneath certain words. The program runs fine and there are no warnings mentioned. So what is the meaning of these wavy lines.
e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/python - I get the line under usr and python

# generated by accessing registry using another script written in VBScript.
# The scripts can do the follwing things.

- I get wavy lines under the words registry and following.
```

I need these comments as I may run the module on its own later. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Turn spell-checking off?

Comment: Indeed, you have a typo: "follwing"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neil speaks the truth, except for telling you to turn it off -- spell check in comments is quite helpful -- those who come after will thank you for ensuring they can read your comments without trying to decode random spelling errors.

The lines are simply pointing out words your IDE thinks are spelled wrong. I don't know why it doesn't understand "registry", but you have, in fact, misspelled "following" (as "follwing"). Fix the latter, ignore the former (or add it to the dictionary, <s>don't remember if there's a convenient mechanism for that</s> There is! See Macke's helpful comment below.).

Comment: Ctrl-1 - Quick Fix has "add to dictionary" .. if you've configured a user dictionary somewhere (it will complain about it...)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Fixed the typo. Added a user defined dictionary (incidentally I had worked on creating something like this years ago :)). Now those annoying lines are gone. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Might be this is just a spellchecker. You have a typo "follwing" instead of "following".